# Book about a master lock picker

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I read this book over ten years ago when I had checked it out from my local library so it probably is much older than that. It was a stand alone novel.

The main line of the story is that there is a thief who is one of the worlds best at breaking into places. He was incredibly good at picking locks and security systems. He gets a document and starts investigating a mystery leading him eventually to breaking into Area 51. During his entry he has to use a neoprene suit as well as other things for blocking human smells, heat, ammonia and co2 in order to defeat the monitors. A small tear on his neoprene breaks off and the security see a small heat spot, assuming it is a rabbit or some other animal. He continues with little problem. Also during the break in he ‘sees’ with his instruments an unknown type of monitor. After studying his data he understands how to get past the mystery monitor even though he has no idea what it was looking for. He finds and communicates with a friendly alien who was being held hostage. The alien lives under sand mostly. He released it and it went out into the desert. During most of this he teams up with another person but I can’t remember anything particular about his partner in all this.

Comment: I also highly recommend visiting https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question for tips on how to elicit more details from your memory about the book in question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*[Nobody's Safe](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0385492588)* by Richard Steinberg

> Gregory Picaro is the finest safecracker and break-in artist in the world. There is no safe, no lock, no security system that can keep him out. By combining touch with technology, insight with improvisation, Greg's world is just one big, open door.
>
> But some things are better left locked away. One evening, on a seemingly routine apartment burglary, Greg is caught with his guard down. Concealed in the owner's closet, Greg covertly witnesses an interrogation of his mark by three men in dark, conservative suits. Unable to crack the owner for the combination to his hidden safe, they torture and murder him in cold blood. Greg keeps his cool, and as the men in black regroup to dispose of the body, Greg picks the safe clean. What he finds in the stash is both perplexing and revelatory, and something that the highest and hidden levels of the government will kill to keep secret.

[This review](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R1THN38BOE3PV6/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=0385492588) mentions the Area 51 connection:

> The government will stop at nothing to kill him and retrieve the stolen papers. What is this valuable information, and why are so many people afraid of it becoming public knowledge? Well, it has to do with an incident that happened in Roswell, New Mexico in 1947 and the government cover-up which followed .... Thankfully, because I knew what to expect (due to the book reviews)and am somewhat familiar with Area 51 here in Nevada, I found myself enjoying Picaro's encounter with Joe and Max.

Found with a search for `novel "area 51" burglar`

Comment: Book sample https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=nAc5FEemnHAC&pg=PT219&lpg=PT219&dq=Nobody%27s+Safe+Richard+Steinberg+%22sneak%22&source=bl&ots=bKZpD5tKrj&sig=ACfU3U0IZRduZjpnBq63FMjgpjiccoL6Gw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj03Pev0afsAhVhxIsKHcLmBrwQ6AEwAXoECAQQAg#v=snippet&q=ammonia&f=false

Comment: Thank you! That was the book. For some reason my searches just were not working.

Comment: It took me a few searches. :) Don't forget to clock the checkmark to accept it.

Comment: Available on internet archive: https://archive.org/details/nobodyssafe00stei_0